# Using svg.js with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser, svg.js

I'm making a website app using TypeScript, and I want to use the svg.js library.

I'm coding in TypeScript, and automatically compiling into JavaScript which runs in the browser.

Is this possible?  And if so, how?

Answer (score 5):

svg.js provides a .d.ts file so you can use it in typescript out of box.

I am using vscode and it needs no further configuration to provide intellisense.

CommonJS style
[image: CommonJS style]

ES 6 style
[image: ES 6 style]
or
[image: ES 6 style]

vscode integrates js and ts service tightly, so it may provide some kind of auto detection. I never used Atom but I think you can explicitly declare your reference using [Triple-Slash Directives](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html)

```
/// <reference path="path/to/yourTypeDeclaration.d.ts" />
// your code follows
```

If importing this still not helps, you may lack some kind of language service plugins.

Comment: Great, so it's possible.  But how?

Comment: @Magmatic import svg.js and just use it? What is your question?

Comment: You mention that it comes with a ".d.ts" file, but you never import it.  How does my IDE (Atom) know about this file?  Your code never mentions it.

Comment: @Fuzzyma do you maybe know why `select()` method [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387057/using-svg-select-method-with-class-selector-of-the-svg-js-library-doesnt-work/49387204#49387204) properly with typescript? Does it look like the bug?

Comment: @magmatic - I don't know. I guess you need to reference the atom docs here

Comment: @mpro could be that this methods is missing in the d.ts file. You can add it via PR

Comment: Weird, import does not find svg. But in the svg folder in node_modules is a d.ts. I'm on a simple TypeScript (3.4) project with webpack (4.32). And svg.js 3.0.

Comment: solved: Use `"moduleResolution": "node",` in tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 1):

Quite late to the party but since I have wasted most of the day struggling to use svg.js from typescript I want to share the solution:

First (of course) you need to install the svg.js via npm.

```
npm install svg.js --save
```

Installed package contains the so called typedef file `svg.js.d.ts`.

You will also need to setup webpack or your favorite packager in order to prepare package for the web.

In your '.ts' file you paste:

```
import * as SVG from 'svg.js';

function a() {
    let draw = SVG(window.document.body).size('100%', '100%')

    draw.rect(400, 400).fill({ color: '#f00', opacity: 1 })
}


window.onload = (event) => {
    a()
};
```

This will render a red rectangle.