# Using SVG.select() method with class selector of the svg.js library doesn't work with typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, svg.js

I'm testing [svg.js](http://svgjs.com/) library with typescript and having some problems with [usage of CSS selectors](http://svgjs.com/referencing/#element-select). I would like to select SVG element using `select()` method with class selector. In [the presented fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fd86s71d/6/) it works perfectly with javascript:

```
var circleTwo = SVG.select('circle.circle-01');
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with typescript. Lib is imported like that:

```
import * as SVG from 'svg.js;
```

[image]

When hover on `select()` method, getting the info about second parameter:

[image]

However according to [the documentation](http://svgjs.com/referencing/#element-select)

> Additionally, a second argument can be passed to define the parent element to search in

It seems that it is an optional argument because you can use `select()` method without it:

```
var elements = SVG.select('rect.my-class').fill('#f06')
```

I've played a bit and found how to get rid of this error (**the question is, is this correct approach?**), however I can't use later the `click()` event on the selected element, because of another error:

> Property 'click' does not exist on type 'Set'.

[image]

`testMe()` is the simple method to test the `click()` event on the selected element:

```
  testMe() {
    alert('it works even better!');
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The click handler is available on Element, however select() returns a Set, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the type definitions are wrong. Thats not your fault, you should open a bug report. Until it gets fixed you could work around it:

```
SVG.select('rect.my-class', undefined as any)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will report this bug. Just one more problem left: https://i.stack.imgur.com/owYpq.jpg

Comment: Oh sorry, I've messed up with class and selector, just copy/pasted yours, it should be like that: `let circleTwo = SVG.select('circle.circle-01', undefined as any)`. What docs do you mean?

Comment: are you really sure that `Set` has a click method? (are there docs for it?)

Comment: Right, [here](http://svgjs.com/classes/#svg-set) is the documentation and it seems that it has not.

Comment: Ok, I've got it! `circleTwo.get(0).click(this.testMe)` works

Comment: `SVG.Set` HAS a click method. It has all methods defined on `SVG.Element`. When typescript is not working for you please open a PR with a fix. Noone of us maintainers know typescript and therefore we rely on the community to help us out